# Android - how to integrate text into image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-imageview, textview

I want to create an Activity in my app that has an image chosen by the user and two or more EditTexts below said image where the user writes something. 
After that, text from those EditTexts should be "integrated" into that image, let's say one on the top and one on the bottom of the image. I wrote integrated because I want the text to be a part of the image - those two need to become only one image so I can use an intent to send it to someone's email.

Sorry if the question is badly asked, I just didn't know how to formulate what I wan so I hope you got it.

Comment: Using canvas, and bitmap, you can write your text onto the image. Then save the new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow steps

1. Create one framelayout with **TextView** and **ImageView**
2. Put **EditText** box implement TextWatcher
3. In onTextChanged method of textwatcher set text in textview.
4. You can create Bitmap of framelayout

Comment: I only wanted to know (see a code snippet) how to do the fourth step but I didn't know how to ask it. Thanks anyway, I wasn't aware of the fact that a view can be converted into a bitmap so your answer actually gave me the idea of what I should google and I found it.

Comment: @classicDominic you can create bitmap for framelayout using this code  :     `FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for ViewOverlay

> The first example in this link does exactly what you want to do.
>   http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/14/viewoverlay-when-how-and-for-what-purpose/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a custom/compound view?